# How to load different parts of a web-page from different html files

Tags: html

I am making a local website where I have a number of pages with a lot of common code for header, navigation bar and footer.
I was wondering if there was a way I could use to store the header, footer and other such codes as independent html files, and then  simply link them in the code for the new page.

Comment: There is...and it depends (somewhat) on you language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use server-side includes for using an HTML file into another one. For that, you'll have to make a few changes in your server configuration as well. I'll show you an example of Apache.

Change configuration as mentioned in https://www.linuxtopia.org/HowToGuides/apache_ssi.html

Include the below code in your html file and replace "included.html" with your section html filename

```
<!--#include file="included.html" -->
```

Check more on : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes